Integrated sms_autofill in my flutter project. It unable to read otp from the sms
I am trying to integrate a flutter library sms_autofill. I have added the code as it was suggested.
In initState I added _listenCode();
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _initializeTextControllers();
    _listenCode();
  }

  void _listenCode() async{
     await SmsAutoFill().listenForCode();
  }


    void _initializeTextControllers() {
      for (int i = 0; i < _controllers.length; i++) {
        _controllers[i].addListener(() => _onTextChanged(i));
      }

      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNodes[0]);
      });
   }

And we have method named @override void codeUpdated() which is expected to visit to read otp from sms which is as:
@override
  void codeUpdated() {
    // Handle auto-filled code
    print("codeUpdated Received OTP visited "); // Debug log
    String code = convertStreamToString(SmsAutoFill().code) as String;
    _otp = code;
    print("Received OTP: $code"); // Debug log
    if (code.length == _controllers.length) {
      setState(() {
        for (int i = 0; i < _controllers.length; i++) {
          _controllers[i].text = code[i];
        }
        // Move focus to the next field if needed
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNodes.last);
      });
    }
  }

above all codes  are written under block class _OtpScreenState extends State<OtpScreen> with CodeAutoFill {...}
My sample sms with hash is as :
<#>123456 is your OTP.
AB/C1defgH2
But codeUpdated() block not get visited. So I am unable to read the otp...
I have added permissions like receive sms and read sms in my Androidmanifest file too.
How to get it work? Please Help!
